# Given ten letters : K,K,K,S,S,S,S,S,S,S. Find number of ways to arrange given ten letters such that no K should be there between two S?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given ten letters : K,K,K,S,S,S,S,S,S,S.

How many ways to arrange given ten letters such that **no** letter "K" between two letters "S", example : "KKSSSSSSSK", "KKKSSSSSSS", "SKKSSSSSSK", etc.

I am confused.

I have calculate ways to arrange 10 given letters,
$$\dfrac{10!}{3!\cdot 7!}=120 \text{ ways.}$$ 
Now I want to calculate the complement of "to arrange given ten letters such that no "K" between two "S" ", that is "there is letter "K" between two letters "S"". If I calculate how many ways :
$$8\cdot \dfrac{7!}{2!\cdot 5!}=168\text{ ways.}$$

That is impossible, negative number. $$120-168=-48\text{ ways.}$$

How to solve that combinatorics problem? Please help me :(

Comment: @TheoBendit Not if "SKKSSSSSSK" is a valid string, as indicated.  The interpretation seems to be "No *single* K between two S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require the rule for complements to do this. Just count the ways to arrange

- arrange KKK,S,S,S,S,S and placing remaining S one each at the ends.
- arrange KK,S,S,S,S,S,S,S and placing the remaining K at either end.

Comment: Yes. First, arrange KKK,S,S,S,S,S,S,S = 8 ways, Second, arrange KK,S,S,S,S,S,S,S with K in last position = 8 ways --> "SSSSSSSKKK" deleted because this string belong to first case. Third, arrange KK,S,S,S,S,S,S,S with K in first position = 8 ways. --> "KKKSSSSSSS" deleted because this string belong to first case. So, the many ways are (8)+(8-1)+(8-1)=22. Thank you very much, @Graham Kemp. Now I understand.

Comment: Or $6+8\times 2=22$ my way.

Comment: Okay, @Graham Kemp..